# Is it possible to configure pool size for batch job workflows database in spring-xd

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I have configured Sql Server to be used as batch job workflows database. I followed the suggestion in documentation and it works well.

I wanted to know if the datasource connection is pooled so I can connect to XD in debug mode and catch one of the `JdbcTemplate.update(..)` calls. I can see that the DataSource implementation is `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` and that there is a pool size already configured. Is it possible to have some control over this configuration?

answer to question:

On page 20 of the spring-xd-reference there a note that says:

"Until full schema support is added for Oracle, Sybase and other database, you will need to put
a .jar file in the xd/lib directory that contains the equivalent functionality as these DDL scripts"

Basically you create 2 files with the name pattern of the other examples and place then in the same classpath. The pattern you use in your configuration is used to fetch the file.

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.3.23:1433;databaseName=jobdb
    username: asdf
    password: asdf
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

So just copy both files from mysql and change the mysql part to sqlserver

Comment: Which documentation did you follow for defining the database?

Comment: Answer to long for comment so just added to the question above.